# Problema con condiciones PHP

Tags: php

este es mi problema,
estoy haciendo un formulario para registrar resoluciones, resulta que una de las condiciones debe ser que no pueden haber dos resoluciones activas al mismo tiempo, entonces hice esto:

```
$ques = "SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM resolucion WHERE estado = '1'"; 
$eje=mysql_query($consul);
$reso = mysql_fetch_assoc($eje);
   .El estado es 1, ya que 1 es activo y 0 inactivo

if($reso['total']<1){
  me ejecuta la actualización
}elseif($reso['total']>=1){
  no ejecuta la actualización
}
```

El problema es que como le estoy diciendo que si las resoluciones activas son mayor o igual 1, no me permita la ejecucion de la actualizacion, pero teniendo en cuenta que quiero actualizar una resolucion que esta activa no me dejaría porque se esta teniendo en cuenta esa resolucion, es decir, ya hay una resolución activa y esa es la que quiero editar pero no me deja, pero con esta validacion puedo evitar que se registren dos o mas resoluciones activas, pero no dejandome editar la que ya esta activa.

Comment: No tienes el código u id de la resolución que esta 'activa'?

Comment: No entendí tu pregunta. ¿A qué te refieres con *editar*  una resolución? ¿Por qué usas un `elseif` en el código y no simplemente un `else`
?

Answer (score 0):

La condición quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
if(int() $reso['total'] == 1){
    echo "Ejecuto la actualización";
} else {
    echo "No ejecuto la actualización";
}
```

La conversión cast puede estar de más, pero podría ser útil si los valores te los retorna de tipo cadena y pueda que impida hacer una correcta comparación.

Answer (score -1):

intenta con esto a ver:

if($reso['total']=1){
  me ejecuta la actualización
}elseif($reso['total']>=1){
  no ejecuta la actualización
}

Debe ser igual "=" a uno, porque "menor que" 1 sería 0 o menos.

Comment: Querras decir `if($reso['total']==1)` sino hay doble `=` siempre entraría en "me ejecuta la actualización"